# Derivative of magnitude of position vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I have encountered this derivative in the context of orbital physics but I cannot understand the steps taken to achieve the last line of the equation.

$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{\vec r\cdot\vec r}$$

$$=\frac{\vec r}{r}\cdot\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$$ 
Where $r=|\vec r|$

My attempt:$$\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{\vec r\cdot\vec r}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\vec r \cdot \vec r}{r}$$
$$=\frac{r((\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\cdot \vec r)+(\vec r\cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}))-\frac{dr}{dt}(\vec r \cdot \vec r)}{r^2}$$
$$=\frac{r((\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\cdot \vec r)+(\vec r\cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}))}{r^2}-\frac{dr}{dt}$$
$$=\frac{((\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\cdot \vec r)+(\vec r\cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}))}{r}-\frac{dr}{dt}$$

I have tried writing $\sqrt{\vec r\cdot\vec r}$ as $\frac{\vec r \cdot \vec r}{r}$ and then using the quotient rule, but I get an erroneous result. I believe I am mistreating the dot product in my working or something else that is not apparent to me.

I would like to know steps taken to achieve this result. Thanks

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: @J.G.The derivative shown in my question is the one I encountered, I cannot understand the steps taken to achieve it - specifically the last line.

Comment: Edit your own attempts into the question, otherwise we can't see what mistake you made that introduced a factor of $2$.

Comment: @J.G. I do not know how to treat the dot product. I found that my prior working was wrong.

Comment: But if we *saw* your prior working, we could say, "you went wrong here".

Comment: @J.G. I have added my new attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

continuing Your attempt, last line:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dr}{dt}&=2\frac{\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\cdot\vec{r}}{r}-\frac{dr}{dt}\\
2\frac{dr}{dt}&=2\frac{\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\cdot\vec{r}}{r}\\
\frac{dr}{dt}&=\frac{\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}\cdot\vec{r}}{r}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Haha, I cannot believe I did not see it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the following substitution 
                    $$\vec r\cdot\vec r=u,$$
and perform differentiation to get the required result.
          $$\frac{dr}{dt}= \frac{d}{dt} \sqrt u $$
                   $$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt u}\frac{du}{dt}$$
                    $$=\frac{1}{2r}\frac{d}{dt}(\vec r\cdot\vec r)$$
                     $$=\frac{1}{2r}(2\vec r\cdot\frac{d\vec r}{dt})$$
                    $$=\frac{\vec r}{r}\cdot\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help